# Prism - region.add and regionManager.AddToRegion works differently

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, prism-5

I was under the impression that the following two code statements are analagous

```
var region = regionManager.Region["SomeRegion"]
region.Add(container.Resolve<SomeView>());
```

and

```
regionManager.AddToRegion("SomeRegion", container.Resolve<SomeView>());
```

but as shown [in my project](https://github.com/rohits79/PrismRegionAmbiguity), they both yield different results - what surprises me is that with regionManager.AddToRegion do not need to use Scoped Regions, but with region.Add we need scoped regions.

Please [clone the repo](https://github.com/rohits79/PrismRegionAmbiguity.git), build and run the project, you should get an exception that ViewB is already registered. Now open TestModule.cs (see below) and comment "region.add" lines, and uncomment regionManager.AddToRegion, you will see the solution works perfectly.

I have gone through the docs and have seen projects intermittently using region.Add and regionManager.AddToRegion, but seems the API works differently.

https://github.com/rohits79/PrismRegionAmbiguity/blob/master/TestModule/TestModule.cs#L22-29

**Update**

Noticed that if i add three lines of AddToRegion then application blows up

```
regionManager.AddToRegion("ViewA", unityContainer.Resolve<ViewA>());
```

however it takes only two lines of

```
region.Add(container.Resolve<ViewA>());
```

Does this not look like an issue in Prism, wonder why AddToRegion works without creating scope?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this in the past.  I never took the time to look into it because it's not that big of a deal.  AddToRegion actually calls Region.Add, so I'm not really sure why this would happen off the top of my head.  I think this depends on the Region type, because calling region.Actiavte will invoke the error immediately.

Just so you know, if you have multiple instances of a region you MUST ALWAYS use scoped regions.

Comment: Yes it is very weird in fact, i will take a shot at it. I could trace all the way to RegionManagerRegistrationBehavior, the second time we add view via view-discovery, it does not Register the Region, however the third time it does and throws exception. To me it looks like a bug, do you think i should open up a ticket (apologies i cross posted it, as I think it is a bug). For now i will stop using AddToRegion though.